# How to get name of dynamically loaded library in linux from within the library that has been opened using ::dlopen?

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic, shared-libraries

in windows one can use GetModuleFileName. what about linux?

Answer (score 3):

dladdr() is a non-standard (not part of POSIX) function that works on most Linux boxes and in OSX. Since it is non standard there are no guarantees, but it should be there since you specified Linux.